# Python Dictionary calls Dictionary but TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to call another dictionary from the result of calling a dictionary. However, there is an error.

```
>>> dict1 = {1:'apple', 2:'mango', 3:'pear'}
>>> dict2 = {'apple': 'jason', 'mango': 'mary', 'pear':'susan'}
>>> print(dict1[1]['apple'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The desired output is: `jason`

Comment: will you please try `print (dict)`?

Comment: @Lafada Thank you for your reply. Martijn Pieters has just provided a clear solution to the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the return value of the first lookup into a lookup for the second:

```
dict2[dict1[1]]
```

`dict1` holds strings, not the `dict2` dictionary, so just pass that resulting string *to* `dict2` when looking up:

```
>>> dict1 = {1:'apple', 2:'mango', 3:'pear'}
>>> dict2 = {'apple': 'jason', 'mango': 'mary', 'pear':'susan'}
>>> dict1[1]
'apple'
>>> dict2['apple']
'jason'
>>> dict2[dict1[1]]
'jason'
```

Comment: @MartijinPieters Thank you for your reminder! Thanks Martijin!